# Moving old encrypted SSD into new PC

Tags: 16.04, ssd

My laptop died and I have some important files on that SSD. What can I do?

It's encrypted, but I know the password and everything. If I install grub via Ubuntu Live it helps? Or it's something I can do?

Comment: Is it a system disk? Or is it just some extra disk for data? Anyway, I guess it's encrypted with LUKS?

Comment: It's encrypted with the default encryption. I mean I selected the encryption option when I installed Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: cryptsetup should help you then